# Can I get gimp manual instruction offline?

Tags: 12.04, gimp

Can I get gimp manual instruction offline?

[image: gimp manual instruction]

Comment: wow! I am just getting a votedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install gimp-help-en` will install the docs for offline usage.